# Gemfire region synchronization

Tags: java, distributed-caching, gemfire

I am using gemfire and currently have a client and a server. Now, the server dinamically creates some subregions in a region and puts some objects in there. I am trying to retrieve the objects with the client but I can't see the objects or the subregions. How can I synchronize the regions? Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, you need to use the DynamicRegionFactory for creating distributed dynamic regions. The gemfire docs were pretty clear on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic regions behave the same as the other regions in your cache and assumes the attributes of its parent region. You must begin with non-dynamic parent regions. Check if this region is working correctly. Synchronization should work this is most probably the problem with configurations. Use GF monitor to check your regions in distributed system.

Another solution is create remote function wich will create regions. In this case you can create portion regions and root regions. This solution is used in GemFire modules for Hibernate L2 cache.